# Required keyword causes error even if member initialized in constructor

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have the following code. The two lines that create a `TestClass` instance fail with the errors shown.

I would expect the first one to fail because a required property is not initialized. However, the second one calls a constructor that *does* initialize the required property. Why does that one fail?

And what is an *attribute constructor*?

```cs
void Main()
{
    TestClass test1 = new(); // <== Error CS9035 Required member 'TestClass.Name' must be set in the object initializer or attribute constructor
    TestClass test2 = new(""); // <== Error CS9035 Required member 'TestClass.Name' must be set in the object initializer or attribute constructor
}

class TestClass
{
    public required string Name { get; set; }
    
    public TestClass()
    {
        
    }
    
    public TestClass(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: New to me, but it looks like (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/required) you need to set the `[SetsRequiredMembers]` attribute on your second constructor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't checked out this new feature too much yet but it looks like it only "plays nice" with `records` and other new constructs, not ordinary classes.

Based on [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/required), only the class-level primary constructor will automatically fulfill this; otherwise, your constructor has to have `System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SetsRequiredMembersAttribute`. Like:

```
class TestClass
{
    public required string Name { get; set; }

    public TestClass()
    {

    }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SetsRequiredMembersAttribute]
    public TestClass(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

I *thought* this would work but it gives the same error:

```
record TestClass(string Name)
{
    public required string Name { get; set; } = Name;
}
```

So I guess this is a partial answer.

Comment: Note this attribute asserts the constructor sets all required properties/fields but doesn’t validate that assertion.  If a new required property is added in the future without setting that property in the attributed constructor, the compiler won’t complain.

Comment: @Moho: And that sounds like something that could be addressed in the future.

Answer (score 2):

> The required modifier indicates that the field or property it's applied to must be initialized by an object initializer.

A constructor is not an "object initializer".  The object initializer is the curly-braced code block that can optionally follow the instantiation of an object:

```
var x = new TestClass { Name = "" };
```

Comment: I know what an initializer is. It's just that the obvious intent is that the member gets initialized. And it is.

Comment: It’s a bad feature that will lead to this confusion, but clearly their intent is not what you think it is per the unambiguous documentation.

Comment: I think their intent is to allow `#nullable enable` without huge constructors. For that purpose, this keyword makes a great deal of sense.

Comment: If the Name property is only initialized during construction then change the property set to init then drop the "required" keyword. Like the questioner I feel that the required keyword has fallen short of my expectation that it would be a full solution for nullable reference type ambiguity.